# XML Processor supporting schema 1.1

Tags: java

I want to to write a schema in xsd 1.1. Can somebody let me know if there is any Java xml processor supporting schema 1.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK [saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/about/intro.xml) 9.3 has complete implementation of schema 1.1 and apache [xercess](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) 2.11 supports only  partialy. BTW Schema 1.1 specifications have not yet been released for production use.

Comment: Thanks for answer but isn't saxon commercial software?